# VS 2012 Code Analysis reports C6054 warning (Zero termination missing) in commdlg.inl

Tags: visual-studio-2012, warnings, code-analysis, null-terminated

The company I work for has a string library that we are starting to use Visual studios 2012 code analysis tools with. The string library project settings has Code analysis enabled and our rule set is vanilla Microsoft Native Recommended Rules. When I build the project and look under the Code Analysis window it has two C6054 warnings (Zero termination missing) on line 266 and 307 in the file `commdlg.inl`. I have tried to suppress this message but I can't save the file because it's read only. I also don't want to turn off this warning for the string library or any other library we are building. I would like these warnings in Microsoft's `commdlg.inl` file to go away so that we can focus on C6054 warnings that come from just our source files. Ideas / suggestions?

Comment: To make the warnings from Microsoft's files go away you need to fix **your calls** to `GetFileTitleA` and `GetFileTitleW`.